# UIPopoverController (swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, uipopovercontroller, uipickerviewcontroller

trying to get UIPopoverController to show me a uipickerviewcontroller on iPad

```
    let popOver = UIPopoverController()
    popOver.delegate = self
    popOver.setContentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true)
```

Error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController init] is not a valid initializer. You must call -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:].'
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: how do i make it work probely ? i can't make the init medtode in swift. and google only shows obj-c medthodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
let popOver = UIPopoverController(contentViewController:imagePicker)
```